# Unable to import python module from subdirectory

Tags: python, module, importerror

My structrue

```
/api/__init__.py
/api/api.py
/database_access/__init__.py
/database_access/databaseaccess.py
/database_access/models/__init__.py
/database_access/models/manufacturer.py
```

`manufacturer.py`

```
class Manufacturer:
    # methods here
```

And `databaseaccess.py`

```
import pymongo
from models import manufacturer # <-- unable to import 'models'

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

computer_parts_database = myclient["computer_parts"]
part_types = computer_parts_database["manufacturers"]
parts = computer_parts_database["parts"]

class DatabaseAccess:
    manufacturers = computer_parts_database["manufacturers"]


da = DatabaseAccess()
#mf = Manufacturer.init2(1, "Advanced Micro Devices", "AMD")
#da.manufacturers.insert_one(mf.toObject())
```

I'm unable to get the `manufacturer` module to load. The same happens with `import models` and `import models.manufacturer`

I get the same problem in `api.py`, if I want to access the `databaseaccess` module I'm not sure how

Comment: It depends where is the entrypoint for your application.
If it is somewhere in `database_access`, then you should probably import your class as
`from database_access.models import manufacturer`

Comment: can you tell me if there is an error. If yes, what does it say

Comment: That's still giving me `Unable to import 'database_access'`

Comment: @RMR_MD It's always an `Unable to import` error

Comment: I've updated my question to include another module that can't access it

Answer (score 0):

Something which I hadn't noticed was I had an `__init__.py` at the root. I removed this and the errors went away

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using PyCharm (or something like that), but instead of them the simple python 32-bit or 64-bit:
Go to Command prompt and write "pip install _____". _____ stands for the name of the module you are trying to install.
If you are using PyCharm:
Go to "File" (up, left) and click on it. Then press on settings. After that a new window will appear with some buttons on the left side. Click on the triangle of the button with the name of your project. Then there will be two buttons. Press on Project interpreter. There you will find the names of all your modules that are (in your case will) (and some others) already installed in your project. Press on the + (up, right) and then you have to write the name if the module you are needing. Click on it and then press on the install button (down, left). Wait for it to install and then you can use it. You will have to do this every time you start a new project.
If you are using something else in Python:
Good Luck, as I don't know the answer.

Without doing this it won't work (what you are trying to do).
Hope you understand everything